# How to transfer hashmaps from one class to another in java

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

I have built a hashmap for documents in java. How can I use the initialized in one class in different class without rerunning program again to fill in the values again? Currently I use get functions in other program to run it again and get values? I would like to store hashmaps in one program so that I can reuse them in a different program without having to write into a file or rerunning the program

Comment: Read about serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize it in a file.

Comment: I have tried that. But one is a hashmap of hashmaps and the inner hashmap has all null values.